# Profile Press Plugin Wordpress, How to use shortcodes in template files?

Tags: wordpress

well I am trying to make authors page, Profiles of each person and I need short codes to be in the authors code but the documentation says it should be in
http://your site.com/profile/demo for user “demo”

how would I use the shortcodes to get data in authors.php?

Comment: I  am just confused how to get authors id or something that I can use in wp_query() to get the authors post in custom template.
 The plugin demands that profile should be in http://your site.com/profile/author_name.
I have tried many things as
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23829/how-to-display-posts-by-current-user-author-in-a-custom-page-template

But can not find specific answers